# Grails Searchable Plugin for multiple domain classes and multiple search fields with a single submit button

Tags: plugins, grails, searchable

I have multiple domain objects and having one to many, many to many relationships and search data comes from couple of tables and it is always same. I implemented Searchable plugin in my app and able to retrieve results when I have single search field like this:

```
<g:form url='[controller: "searchable", action: "searchContact"]' id="searchableForm" name="searchableForm" method="get">
    <g:textField name="query" value="${params.query}" size="40"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Search Contact" />
</g:form>.
```

But I have multiple text fields, check boxes and g:select boxes to get searchTerm. Based on any one of fields or multiple search selections I have to get search results. How to include all search fields in between  and having a single submit button for all the params. Here is my search action code:

```
def searchContact = { 
    if (!params.query) {
        return [:]
    }
    try {
        String searchTerm = params.query
        println searchTerm
        return [searchResult: searchableService.search(searchTerm, params)]
    } catch (SearchEngineQueryParseException ex) {
        return [parseException: true]
    }
}
```

Quick suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass all the terms in one String query separating each token/word by a space, so for example if you have two Domain classes one called Person and another one called Job and you search for "John" and "Engineer", your String query should be "John Engineer" and that should get you both domain objects.

Is that kind of what you are looking for?

Comment: Refer to my <g:form> code above, I want this <g:form> </g:form> block include all the search params which I enter on UI, either one or few. And it have to have one Search button to submit for all or one search field selection. When I include one search param in <g:form> </g:form> its working fine, but if I put more, its giving exceptions. Any ideas. Code snippet will help me more considering 3 domain classes, 3 search params from each one domain and search closure also.

Comment: You have two options, 1. take each value and concatenate them on the client using Javascript or 2. put all the values inside the form and send them all to the server and then in your action concatenate them to form the query value.

Comment: I will go with option 2. Can you give the snippet of code based on my action searchContact shown in my original questions. Thanks for the help.

Comment: All the values will go inside the params object like the query one does now, so you grab them from the params object like params.value1 and concatenate that to the query String object.

Comment: Can you refactor my method and send. One other thing is my search should be with single search param or combination of multiple search params. Please refactor my method if you find sometime today,

Comment: I have a domain object which has lastUpdated field. I added lastUpdated to Searchable closure in domain and I want to have lastUpdated value as one my search field in format of (YYYY/MM/DD). How can I achieve this, Any ideas please.